# How can I extract a substring in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have this string, for instance:

```
str1 = "UNCID_999277.TCGA-CV-7254-01A-11R-2016-07.111118_UNC11-SN627_0167_AD09WDACXX_TAGCTT.txt"
```

I would like to extract this substring, for instance:

```
TCGA-CV-7254
```

I tried something link this:

```
gsub(pattern = "(*.)(TCGA*)(.*)",
   replacement = "\\2",
   x = nameArq)
```

But it returns:

```
[1] "UNCID_999277TCGA"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `*` is a quantifier meaning the preceding token is repeated zero to infinity times. Since it's after `A`, it's looking for multiple `A`s. You need a quantifier on a wildcard token `.` instead.

Comment: *I would like to extract this substring, for instance* - and what is so specific about it? How can we help you if you do not explain the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. In the first parentheses, the period needs to come first (this means "repeat any character any number of times"). You also need some unique endpoint for the second part of your regex.

```
gsub(pattern = "(.*)(TCGA.*4)(.*)", 
     replacement = "\\2", 
     x = str1)
```